# IOException when adding elements from one list to another

Tags: c#, .net, filestream

I have got a weird problem when trying to add elements read from a binary file to a `BindingList<Type>`. This is the faulty piece of code:

```
BindingList<Type> tmpList = null;
using (FileStream serializedListStream = File.OpenRead(_kReificableDroidsListPath))
{
   BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();

   //Temporary list so that ListChanged event is fired
   //upon adding new types
   tmpList = serializer.Deserialize(serializedListStream) as BindingList<Type>;
   foreach (Type droidType in tmpList)
   {
       ReificableDroids.Add(droidType);
   }
}
```

The Visual Studio debugger show me this exception:

`System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Zoneur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Droid TP1\Droid TP2\bin\Debug\reificable_droids_list.bin' because it is being used by another process.`

What I understood is that the file needed to be closed, so I took my `foreach` loop out of the `using` statement like so:

```
BindingList<Type> tmpList = null;
using (FileStream serializedListStream = File.OpenRead(_kReificableDroidsListPath))
{
   BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();

   //Temporary list so that ListChanged event is fired
   //upon adding new types
   tmpList = serializer.Deserialize(serializedListStream) as BindingList<Type>;
}
foreach (Type droidType in tmpList)
{
    ReificableDroids.Add(droidType);
}
```

The exception isn't thrown anymore but I can't understand what the problem is... `ReificableDroids` is a property of type `BindingList<Type>`.

Also, if I keep my `foreach` loop in the `using` statement and just print the type name to the console like this:

```
foreach (Type droidType in tmpList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(droidType.GetType().ToString());
}
```

No exception is thrown either.

Does anyone know what might cause this exception to be thrown in a using statement?

Comment: Are you creating earlier in your code logic the `_kReificableDroidsListPath` file? I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: The file exists on my disk and is created earlier. Plus I handle the exception if the file was not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that this exception could have anything to do with place you are looping over loaded data. It must be something related which is not displayed here.

Checklist:

- How many times did this behavior occur?
- Do you handle `AddingNew` or `ListChanged` events of the `BindingList` and maybe access the file from there again?
- Do you have multiple concurrent calls to method you displayed?

Comment: I was indeed accessing my file in my `ListChanged` handler! I am refactoring my code to adapt to the MVVM pattern and forgot to remove this handler.. Thanks! Nice deduction :)